# Inviting new user to private channel after inviting him by Slack API

Tags: api, slack, slack-api

I invited new user into slack team using slack API method `users.admin.invite`. I need to join him into some public and some private channels. Channels I gave as params in my inviting request, but with private channels I have trouble. It is not channels and it have another method to join user into it. 
Method `groups.invite` need userId to join him. 
Is it possible to add this user in the slack private channels (groups) using slack API?

Comment: Have you tried putting the ID (not the name) of the private channel in the `user.admin.invite` request? It worked some time ago, might still do. You can use `groups.list` to get the IDs of all private channel.

Comment: I tried, but I receive error, because privat channels ID did not find in channel list, slack named it groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The undocumented API method `users.admin.invite` has a `channels` property, where you can specify a list of IDs for the channels your want a new user to be automatically invited to.

This also works with private channels (I just tested it to confirm). All you need to do is to specify a private channel ID instead, which start with a `G` instead of a `C`.

You can use the API method `groups.list` to get the correct private channel ID. (private channels are called groups in the Slack API)

Example request:

```
https://slack.com/api/users.admin.invite?token=TOKEN&email=name@example.com&channels=G12345678
```

If you still getting errors using this approach than its most likely due to other issues, e.g. Slack does not recognize the email address or your access token does not have the admin right.

For more details please see the unofficial documentation of [`users.admin.invite`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.admin.invite.md) on github, which I have updated accordingly.

Comment: When i tryed to add private channels( started from G), I receive responce with error 'channel_not_found'. When I send only public channels - there are all okay. What is wrong?

Comment: My guess is that the user that is associated with the access token you are using is not a member of that private channel. Even admins can not see private channels, which they have not been invited to. Try inviting that user to the private channel and it should work.

Comment: Do You mean try to use Api token thats user which already joined that privat channel, in which I need to invite new member?

Comment: Basically yes. The user which is linked to the access token you are using (usually the user that created it)  needs to be a member of that private channel.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this API endpoint isn't currently documented by Slack because it's still in development and could change in the future(which may be what you're running into now). Here's a link to a github issue talking more about it. https://github.com/slackhq/slack-api-docs/issues/30

I was able to find a github with documentation for the undocumented slack API endpoints, but those could have changed since they're not official https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.admin.invite.md

From these unofficial API documentation it seems like you'll have to pass in the channelID instead of the channel name. To get channel IDs you'll just need to call the channels.list end point

Comment: I know about this method and I use it. But private channels can not by joined by including their ids in pfrfms of this method.